# Persisting Data During Form Wizard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, forms, wizard

I currently have a 3 step form wizard that takes a decent amount of information from the user. The first page contains multiple text fields, the second a grid, and the third a few more text fields. I'm currently persisting the data after each step, and after each row is added to the grid, in the database. The reason being so that the user will not lose the data they entered due to systems failure or session timeout. I'm wondering if this is an ideal way to persist this information, or if there is a better way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Store them in hidden's after 1st step

Comment: or in Local Storage (in the browser)

Comment: @LasseEdsvik I'm currently storing the data in a hidden field as Json, my concern is if the user session times out, or if they accidentally leave the wizard

Comment: @Will Hidden fields obviously don't persist if the session dies but if that's a problem then you need to look at the alternatives. If you have a long wizard process over many pages with lots of fields then it might aid user experience to persist it in the database. Most websites don't persist form data but it depends completely on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to persist data:

- Resend the posted user entered data back to the view, then use
  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Whatever)` to ensure it returns back
  to the controller on post. This will continue to keep the user data in the viewmodel, you just keep passing it from view to view.
- Save the user data in the session `HttpContext.Session["UserFormData"];`
- Alternatively, you can save the user entered data to the database,
  as you are currently doing. I personally prefer this as it
  resolves the issue of session timeouts.